# Missing posts in Stream

Tags: stream, facebook-fql

This issue were removed by a reason I can't figure out. Maybe there are problems with my links below, so I try in text instead:

In Graph API Explorer, I am writing:

`SELECT message, updated_time from stream where source_id in (SELECT uid2 from friend where uid1 = me()) and updated_time>1369423637`

In the result I miss a lot of the post from my timeline (that appear in the timeline above the last post in the result). I might understand that posts posted by someone that is NOT my friend doesn't show up, but some missing posts are plain text posts directly as statuses from my friends.

I have tried to search the community, but posts I found were quite old, or not relevant. I'm not sure if it is possible to get all posts from my timeline, but that is the target of my developing. I haven't found any better way, so please help me.

My previous pictures where you can see the missmatch:

Timeline:
[image: my FB timeline]

FQL script:
[image: my FQL script]

If someone is going to vote minus for this, or remove this, please let me know the exact cause.

Comment: I really don't understand why this issue was closed. I have a real problem, and ask with two exact images of my problem, and how it look like. Is there a problem to reach the images, please let me know. But anyhow, I'll try to explain my issue with other words:

Comment: Have you tried using `created_time` instead?

Comment: Thanks. I tried, and the result are handled little bit different. I think I have to elaborate with both of these, and I will get back if I sometime in the future completely understand this (which I currently don't)